# APA Biblatex reference style issue

Tags: apa-style, apacite

I have some issues with the APA Biblatex reference style the current output is:

> This is the in text reference (Badenhorst, Plug, Pelser, & Van Vollenhoven 2002: 10)
>
> Second reference display et al only. (Badenhorst *et al*. 2002: 10)
>
> **References**
>
> Badenhorst, S., Plug, I., Pelser, A., & Van Vollenhoven, A. (2002). Faunal analysis from steinaecker’s horse, the northernmost british military outpost in the kruger national park during the south african war. *Annals of the Transvaal Museum*, 39(10): 57–63.

The in text cite is correct, however there are a few issues with my Reference list and should look like the reference List image below.

1. The year must not be inside parentheses.
2. The Article name should display the proper format in the current output only the first word is Capitalized “Faunal” however in the bib file the name have more than one capital letter.
3. There should not be a (,) comma after the Journal name

**My MWE is :**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,total={160mm,240mm},left=25mm,top=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{A01,
    title = {Faunal analysis from Steinaecker’s Horse, the northernmost British military outpost in the Kruger National Park during the South African War},
    volume = {39},
        number= {10},
    pages = {57--63},
    journaltitle = {Annals of the Transvaal Museum},
    author = {Badenhorst, Shaw and Plug, Ina and Pelser, A.J. and Van Vollenhoven, A.C.},
    date = {2002},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}

% 2nd author in bibliography also display Surname, name
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 

% preceed last author with &
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

% Change Journal Volume to normal from italics.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\apanum{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

% Impliment et al option for more than 2 authors 
\newcommand*{\mkandothers}{\mkbibemph}
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\mkandothers]{andothers}}
    {}}

    
% Display In text reference as (Autor Year:Page)
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}    

% Add colon (:) after Journal edition in stead of comma (,)
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\addperiod\space}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\nopunct}{}{}

% Change the first occurence of 3 or more authors to display their surnames in text and from the 2nd occurence et al.
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\defcounter{maxnames}{6}}%
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

This is the in text reference \autocite[10]{A01}\\

Second reference display et al only. \autocite[10]{A01}\\

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\begingroup
  \setlength{\bibhang}{0pt} % remove indentation 
  \setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip} % Space between each reference entry
  \printbibliography

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

**The desired output should be**

> Badenhorst, S., Plug, I., Pelser, A., & Van Vollenhoven, A. 2002.
> Faunal analysis from Steinaecker’s Horse, the northernmost British
> military outpost in the Kruger national park during the South African
> War. *Annals of the Transvaal Museum* 39(10): 57–63.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure about all the modifications you are trying to make in apa-style for `biblatex` but I have change a bit your MWE to implement both of your desired changes. Be aware that `biblatex-apa` is not meant to be heavily customized.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,total={160mm,240mm},left=25mm,top=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{A01,
    title = {Faunal analysis from Steinaecker’s Horse, the northernmost British military outpost in the Kruger National Park during the South African War},
    volume = {39},
        number= {10},
    pages = {57--63},
    journaltitle = {Annals of the Transvaal Museum},
    author = {Badenhorst, Shaw and Plug, Ina and Pelser, A.J. and Van Vollenhoven, A.C.},
    date = {2002},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}

% 2nd author in bibliography also display Surname, name
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 

% preceed last author with &
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

% Change Journal Volume to normal from italics.
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\apanum{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

% Impliment et al option for more than 2 authors 
\newcommand*{\mkandothers}{\mkbibemph}
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\mkandothers]{andothers}}
    {}}

    
% Display In text reference as (Autor Year:Page)
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}    

% Add colon (:) after Journal edition in stead of comma (,)
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\addperiod\space}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\nopunct}{}{}

% Change the first occurence of 3 or more authors to display their surnames in text and from the 2nd occurence et al.
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\defcounter{maxnames}{6}}%
}
\makeatother

% Disable year parentheses.

\DeclareFieldFormat{apadate}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdatecirca} or test {\ifdateuncertain} }
    {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
    {#1}}

% Remove colon after journal name.

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issuename}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

This is the in text reference \autocite[10]{A01}\\

Second reference display et al only. \autocite[10]{A01}\\

\begingroup
  \setlength{\bibhang}{0pt} % remove indentation 
  \setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip} % Space between each reference entry
  \printbibliography

\endgroup

\end{document}
```